# bootstrap date picker popup

Tags: datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I move Date picker popup to show on right side? Currently it is making me to scroll page down to view the calendar.

```
 <div class ="form-group">
<label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Received Date</label>
<div class="col-sm-2 input-group date" data-date-format="mm-dd-yyyy"> 
<input class="text-input form-control" type="text" name="ARDT" id="ARDT" maxlength="10" />
<span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
</div>
</div>
```

2. How can size the application number filed width to 15 ?

```
<div class ="form-group">
 <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" >Application Number</label>
  <div class="col-sm-3">
   <input  class="text-input form-control" type="text" name="appNumber" id="appNumber" maxlength="15" size="15"/>
 </div>
 </div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tK4f6/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Twitter bootstrap-3 datepicker has option "[orientation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/options.html#orientation)":

> A space-separated string consisting of one or two of “left” or
>   “right”, “top” or “bottom”, and “auto” (may be omitted); for example,
>   “top left”, “bottom” (horizontal orientation will default to “auto”),
>   “right” (vertical orientation will default to “auto”), “auto top”.
>   Allows for fixed placement of the picker popup.